# ipython and silent errors

Tags: python, runtime-error, ipython, silent

I'm new to python and ipython, and getting silent errors: errors that don't show up on console unless I run it in scope. Maybe I setup something wrong, but the problem is this:

```
class test:
  def __init__(self):
    self.only_map = { 'a' : 1 }
  def run (self):
    print 'start'
    self.only_map['c'] = self.only_map['a'] + self.only_map['b']
    print 'done'

obj = test()
obj.run()
```

This prints:

start

There is no error, and it seems like everything is ok. But when I run it line by line, the error is caught:

```
self=obj
print 'start'
self.only_map['c'] = self.only_map['a'] + self.only_map['b']
print 'done'
```

This print:

start

KeyError: 'b'

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can you specify what version you are using? I am using iPython 2.3.0 and I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

1. You may have variables stored in memory. `exit()` and restart
2. Edit in a text editor and paste in with the `%paste` command to make sure you have no editing issue
3. Check what you have declared as a variable with `%whos`

If all else fails, run the code below. It will print out objects of `self` so that you can verify you have no errors...

```
class test:
  def __init__(self):
    self.only_map = { 'a' : 1 }
  def run (self):
    print 'start'
    print self.__dict__
    self.only_map['c'] = self.only_map['a'] + self.only_map['b']
    print 'done'

obj = test()
obj.run()
```